# Shadow mapping with non-directional light

Tags: opengl, shadow-mapping

I'm new to openGL and I was following [this](https://www.opengl-tutorial.org/intermediate-tutorials/tutorial-16-shadow-mapping/) tutorial in which they showed how to make shadow maps but I could't understand how to get it to work for non-directional lights. They have [some instructions](https://www.opengl-tutorial.org/intermediate-tutorials/tutorial-16-shadow-mapping/#spot-lights) on how to extend it to work for point lights as well but I could't understand them and couldn't get it to work when trying to figure it out. Full source code of the tutorial [here](https://github.com/opengl-tutorials/ogl/tree/master/tutorial16_shadowmaps) (simple version .cpp file and shadowmapping shaders) and here follows the snippets I'm working on. First the code for the directional light that works well:

main .cpp file

```
// Compute the MVP matrix from the light's point of view
glm::vec3 lightInvDir = glm::vec3(0.5f,2,2);
glm::mat4 depthProjectionMatrix = glm::ortho<float>(-10,10,-10,10,-10,20);
glm::mat4 depthViewMatrix = glm::lookAt(lightInvDir, glm::vec3(0,0,0), glm::vec3(0,1,0));

glm::mat4 depthModelMatrix = glm::mat4(1.0);
glm::mat4 depthMVP = depthProjectionMatrix * depthViewMatrix * depthModelMatrix;

// Send our transformation to the currently bound shader, 
// in the "MVP" uniform
glUniformMatrix4fv(depthMatrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, &depthMVP[0][0]);

...

// Compute the MVP matrix from keyboard and mouse input
computeMatricesFromInputs();
glm::mat4 ProjectionMatrix = getProjectionMatrix();
glm::mat4 ViewMatrix = getViewMatrix();
//ViewMatrix = glm::lookAt(glm::vec3(14,6,4), glm::vec3(0,1,0), glm::vec3(0,1,0));
glm::mat4 ModelMatrix = glm::mat4(1.0);
glm::mat4 MVP = ProjectionMatrix * ViewMatrix * ModelMatrix;

glm::mat4 normaliseMatrix(
    0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 
    0.0, 0.5, 0.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 0.0,
    0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0
);

// Send our transformation to the currently bound shader, 
// in the "MVP" uniform
glUniformMatrix4fv(MatrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, &MVP[0][0]);
glUniformMatrix4fv(NormaliseID, 1, GL_FALSE, &normaliseMatrix[0][0]);
glUniformMatrix4fv(DepthMatrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, &depthMVP[0][0]);
```

vertex shader

```
// Output position of the vertex, in clip space : MVP * position
gl_Position =  MVP * vec4(vertexPosition_modelspace,1);

ShadowCoord = normaliseMVP * depthMVP * vec4(vertexPosition_modelspace,1);
```

fragment shader

```
// Light emission properties
vec3 LightColor = vec3(1,1,1);

float visibility = texture( shadowMap, vec3(ShadowCoord.xy, (ShadowCoord.z)/ShadowCoord.w) );

color = visibility * LightColor;
```

And I've tried to edit it per their instructions but I had a hard time understanding what to do. I've tried different things but my code looks something something like the following (only showing the edited rows from the snippets above):

main .cpp file

```
glm::vec3 lightPos(5, 20, 20);
glm::mat4 depthProjectionMatrix = glm::perspective<float>(glm::radians(45.0f), 1.0f, 0.1f, 100.0f);
glm::mat4 depthViewMatrix = glm::lookAt(lightPos, lightPos-lightInvDir, glm::vec3(0,1,0));
```

fragment shader

```
float visibility= 1.0f;
if ( texture( shadowMap, ShadowCoord.xy ).z  < ShadowCoord.z ){
    visibility = 0.0f;
}
```

This hasn't worked and I have no idea why or what needs to be done differently. The changes to the fragment shader also throw error messages that I don't know how to resolve.

[image: Directional light]
Image 1: The directional light that works well, roughly what I expect to see from a point light too.

[image: No shadows]
Image 2: Most of my failed attempts show no sign of a shadow.

Comment: I don't see the cube map creation info here, are you using a cube map for the point light shadows?

Comment: Have you divided the ShadowCoord by its "w" component? because of the perspective projection your coordinate is weighted wrong. Whenever you calculate Position = Matrix*Vector and "Matrix" is a perspective projection, you need to divide the result (Position) by its "w" component

Comment: I have not used a cube map, I thought I'd start with getting it to work in just a single direction before implementing omnidirectional. And I believe I have missed dividing by w, thank you.

Comment: @n-l-i does it work now?